# Set partition of strings by suffix

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I have this question:

> Is this collection of subsets a partition on the set of bit strings of length 8:
>
> The set of bit strings that end with 111, the set of bit strings that
> end with 011, and the set of bit strings that end with 00.

My answer would be no, this is not a partition, as it does not accommodate strings that end in 10 or 01 for example. However, it appears that I am incorrect based on the given answer. Is anyone able to explain to me why I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you are **not** wrong, for exactly the reason you stated; the purported partition does not contain e.g. `00000001`.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks guys, this really had me confused. At least it's not me that's wrong this time :)